# irssi: Where do Private messages go?

Tags: irc, irssi

When I first set up irssi, I can easily join a channel, but I'm used to seeing popups when people ping me privately.

In default irssi it appears there is no way of knowing if someone sent you a private message - is there a way to automatically popup unknown private messages in irssi?

Answer (score 7):

Private messages should create another window and highlight it in a different color.

By default, these are the following colors and their meanings in IRSSI:

- **White** - Part/Quit/Join
- **Bold White** - Unread channel messages
- **Bold red/pink** - Unread channel highlights or private messages

[image: irssi window]

See the `[Act: 2,3,4,5]` text? Those numbers represent unread notifications.  `2` is a private message, `3` is a ping in a channel, `4` is an unread message, and `5` is someone joining or leaving.

You can access them by cycling through with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, or by typing `/window N`, where `N` is the window number.